# Why does glDeleteTextures() have three parameters in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm wondering why the function `GLES20.glDeleteTextures()` has **three** parameters in **OpenGL ES 2.0** whereas the "standard" `glDeleteTextures()` only has **two** parameters.

Even in the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml), there are only two parameters.

However, in my program and many forums, the function takes a third parameter (always a `0` from what I've seen).

So, what is this third parameter?

EDIT: other functions have this "problem". `glGetIntegerv()` also takes a seemingly-useless third parameter (still an `int`) in OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: The third param is the offset which in most use cases would be 0. Androids docs show it uses both: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html#glDeleteTextures(int, java.nio.IntBuffer) I can assume the same for other calls. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html for complete list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has noting to do with ES 2.0 compared to other OpenGL versions.

The reference documentation shows the C/C++ OpenGL bindings.

What you're using when you call `GLES20.glDeleteTextures()` are the Java bindings defined for Android. They obviously need to look different because they are for a different programming language. The Java bindings are also not standardized, so they are defined in a way that makes sense to the people responsible for Android.

Answer (score 2):

It's **the offset** (based on the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html#glDeleteTextures(int,%20int[],%20int))).
For example,

```
int[] textures = {id0, id1, id2, id3, id4, id5};
GLES20.glDeleteTextures(2, textures, 3);
```

Here, the number of textures to delete is `2`, from offset `3`.
So only textures with `id3` and `id4` will be deleted.

It may be a common usecase to use the function like this:

```
GLES20.glDeleteTextures(textures.length, textures, 0);
```

Which should delete **all the textures** in the `textures` array.